# web api call get method with different url parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have a set of requirements to implement the get interface:

```
 - api/Item
 - api/Item?name=test
 - api/Item?updated=2016-10-12
 - etc
```

I've defined the methods as:

```
 - get() //returns all items
 - getName([FromUri] string name) 
 - getUpdated([FromUri] string updated)
```

My issue is - if parameter doesn't exist (let's say the call was `api/Item?test=test`), the `get(`) method is called as "test" parameter mapping is not found.

I need to return the error response in this case. Is there any other proper way to read the parameters from URL to meet the interface requirement?

Comment: Use attribute routing...

Comment: Or rethink your route design.  Why not use **api/Item/name/test** or **api/item/updated/2016-10-12**?  Then use a default route map followed by an error route map that handles non-matching routes.

Comment: Thanks guys for pointing into the right direction

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may be looking for something like this

```
[RoutePrefix("api/items")]
public class ItemsController : ApiController
{

    public IHttpActionResult Get()
    {
        return Ok(new List<string> { "some results collection" });
    }

    [Route("names")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetByName([FromUri]string name = null)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name))
        {
            return BadRequest("name is empty");
        }
        return Ok("some result");
    }

    [Route("updates")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetUpdates([FromUri]string updated = null)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(updated))
        {
            return BadRequest("updated is empty");
        }
        return Ok("some result");
    }
}
```

When you invoke these REST endpoints, your REST api calls will look something like

GET **api/items**  to retrieve all items

GET **api/items/names/john** to retrieve by name, if parameter is not supplied, error is returned

GET **api/items/updated/test** to retrieve updates, if parameter is not supplied, error is returned

Comment: Hi. Thank you for you reply. I've modified the method and routing slightly. The method signature is now GetByName(string name = null) and I've set the [Route("name/{name}")] attribute. It now allows to make a call as api/items/name/john. That has solved my issue. Thank you for your sample.